# If statement concerning matrix cell not returning true(java)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, matrix

I have a project for a class that is to solve a maze(matrix), which is simple enough, however i'm having some trouble with an if statement that should validate the usability of the matrix cell, to see if that number is a part of the path.

Here's the test Maze I've created:

```
    // 0 = start
    // 1 = path
    // 2 = wall
    // 3 = end
    // 5 = tried
    // 6 = final path

int [][] maze = {{2,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,2,2},
                {2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2},
                {2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2},
                {2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2},
                {2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1},
                {2,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,2},
                {2,1,2,0,2,2,2,2,2,2},
                {2,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,2},
                {2,2,3,0,2,2,2,2,2,2},};
```

And here is the method to check if the current cell is valid to walk on:

```
private boolean valid (int row, int column) {

    boolean result = false;

    // checks if cell is inside of the matrix
    if (row >= 0 && row < maze.length &&
            column >= 0 && column < maze[0].length) {

        //  checks if cell is not blocked, if it has previously been tried or it's the end
        if (maze[row][column] == 1 || maze[row][column] == 3 || maze[row][column] == 0 || maze[row][column] == 5) {
            result = true;
        }else{

            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

From using print statements I've seen that the problem maybe in the nested if statement. But there might be another problem I am not sure of, which is on the solving method.

```
public boolean solve(int row, int column ) {

    boolean solved = false;

    if (valid(row, column)) {

        maze[row][column] = 5;

        if (maze[row][column] == 1 || maze[row][column] == 0){
            if( !solved){//it's going to call the function it self and move if possible.
                solved = solve(row + 1, column);  // South
                if (!solved)
                    solved = solve(row, column + 1);  // East
                if (!solved)
                    solved = solve(row - 1, column);  // North
                if (!solved)
                    solved = solve(row, column - 1);  // West
            }
            if (solved)  // part of the final path
                maze[row][column] = 7;
        }else if (maze[row][column] == 3) {
            solved = true;
            System.out.println("lol the end");
        }
        //exception here not to leave the maze and case there's no 0
    }
    return solved;
}
```

Comment: This is why debuggers exist.  I would spend some time learning how to use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: well, it compares one time, if not everything is true, it 'll return false

Comment: I haven't tested, but, when you call this line `maze[row][column] = 5;` then when you reach this if: `if (maze[row][column] == 1 || maze[row][column] == 0){` it will always be false... (`if (5 != 0 OR 5 != 1)`, that's what it says) Or am I missing something...?

Comment: which row and column are you passing it that you are expecting to return true and it returns false?

Answer (score 0):

Put the statement

```
    maze[row][column] = 5;
```

just after the next (`if`) statement:

```
    if (maze[row][column] == 1 || maze[row][column] == 0){
```

as it protect to correctly evaluate the condition in this `if` statement.